# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement uvicron (from versions: none)

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip, fastapi

I'm trying to run FastAPI on my RaspberryPi (Ubuntu 22.04 ARM64) with Docker.
Its my `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM python:3.10
RUN pip3 install fastapi
RUN pip3 install uvicron
COPY ./app /app
CMD ["uvicron", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "15400"]
```

Unfortunately there is a problem while installing `uvicron`:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement uvicron (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for uvicron
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
```

It seems to me that the warning about pip version is not a problem, but I enclose just in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such package: https://pypi.org/project/uvicron/ — error 404. I'm sure you need https://pypi.org/project/uvicorn/ or https://pypi.org/project/hypercorn/

```
pip3 install uvicorn
```

or

```
pip3 install hypercorn
```

FastAPI docs [recommend](https://pypi.org/project/fastapi/)

```
pip3 install "uvicorn[standard]"
```

Comment: Oh, so it was typo... Great thanks!